# How to present ads during certain scenes in sprite-kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

This is my first time developing an app using swift and sprite-kit. I would like to integrate adMob into it. I have been searching a solution to my problem but I've had no success.

I have the following code set up inside `GameViewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    bannerView.isHidden = true
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-************************"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    // Create and configure the scene.
    let aspectRatio = skView.bounds.size.height / skView.bounds.size.width
    let scene = MainMenuScene(size:CGSize(width: 320, height: 320 * aspectRatio))
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    showBanner()

}

func showBanner() {
    bannerView.isHidden = false
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["******************"]
    bannerView.load(request)

}
```

This setup displays the ad on all of my scenes perfectly but my question is, how would I be able to make it show on `MainMenuScene.swift` and `GameOverScene.swift` by using NotificationCenter? Both of these are their own class.

Comment: What is MenuScene.swift?

Comment: @ElTomato It is a class. Looks something like so , class MainMenuScene : SKScene {    }

Comment: I don't know the relationship between MainMenuScene ad MenuScene, but if they are brothers and sisters, you may want to create a base SKScene class so that you can subclass it for them with a bool switch for displaying or not displaying the ad.

Comment: @ElTomato I apologize for the confusion, it totally slipped me by! I meant to put MainMenuScene.swift instead so I already edited the question.

Comment: No problem...  Just create a base SKScene class.  Then subclass it for MainMenuScene, GameOverScene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned you can use Notification Center.

Create a key for your notification to avoid typos. You can put this anywhere you like in your project (outside any class or a new .swift file)

```
 extension Notification.Name {
    static let showBannerAd = Notification.Name(rawValue: "ShowBanner")
 }
```

Than in your GameViewController add the observer in ViewDidLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showBanner), name: .showBannerAd, object: nil) // selector is the method to call
```

and in your SKScene(s) you can post the notification like so when you need to show the banner.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.postNotificationName(.showBannerAd, object: nil)
```

Alternatively I have a helper on Github which will make this much easier and cleaner.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/SwiftyAds

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I had already figured it out. I actually did something similar to this and it works like a charm. I'll go ahead and just leave this question with this answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for making. Happy coding